# Determine class type in virtual function

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'd like to do the following:

```
class A {
    protected string _Name;
    protected virtual void f(){ _Name = GetType().Name; // _Name is "A" }
}
class B : A {
    // No override for f() hier.
}
class C : B {
    protected void override f()
    {
       base.f(); // _Name is "C", but I want to get
       // the class name in which _Name is actually set, i.e. "A"
    }
}
```

In other words I'd like to get the name of the class in which a member variable's value is set. How should I do this?

Comment: `_Name = "A"`, no?

Comment: No, when you call `f()` from an instance of `C` you'll get "C" for type name.

Comment: `protected virtual void f(){...}` ? since by default it is `private virtual void f(){...}`

Comment: sorry, typo! corrected it.

Comment: Why not just `_Name = nameof(A);`?

Comment: @rashmatash I think the suggestion was to set `_Name` to the literal string "A" inside `f`.

Comment: I understand, but the actual code is more complex and I don't want to hard-code it.

Comment: But we can only answer the question you asked, not the question you should've asked. If you have a more complex situation it warrants a more complex answer but since you're not asking *that* question or explaining *that* situation, we can't answer it. It really is as simple as that.

Comment: Also, you're explaining what you *don't* want, please explain more about what you *do* want. Again, what does it mean that you say "get the name of the class in which a member variable's value is set". Do you want a property itself to figure out where the code that attempts to set it is located? Because that's not the question you've asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woudn't say `this.GetType().Name`, I would say `typeof(A).Name` and in class B 
`typeof(B).Name`

so each class which overrides the method sould say `typeof(classname).Name`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest soloution is this:

```
class A 
{
    protected string _Name;
    protected virtual void f() { 
        _Name = typeof(A).Name; //or nameof(A)
    }
}
```

If you want to be more fancy for some reason and you want to get the base type of any class, you can use a method like the following:

```
public static Type GetBaseType(Type type)
{
    Type currentType = type;
    while(currentType.BaseType != typeof(object) 
       && currentType.BaseType != null)
    {
        currentType = currentType.BaseType;
    }
    return currentType;
}
```

I haven't checked this code, it might be that it doesn't work properly for structs.

**EDIT:** Actually, you can't derive from structs anyway, so it should work for them. However, enums are derived from byte/short/int/long, I don't know how it behaves for them.

Comment: You can't inherit structs anyway.

Comment: With your last example, if people come in with a `struct` or `enum` type, they will get `typeof(System.ValueType)` as the returned value.

Comment: Aah, I remember that there is some inheritance with structs possible even though you can't inherit them in C#. They always break these things with reflection :-)